# How to wait for all promises to be resolved before returning data?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

There 3 functions first one is my promise.

```
    fnGetIps : function () {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          var err = [], path = getBaseUrl();
          restGet(path + NAMES, function (res, edges) {
          if (res === undefined) {
              reject("Unable to get data");
          } else {
              resolve(edges);
        }
     });
   });
 },
```

Second one is where i use my promise.

```
fnGetData: function(obj){
 var promise_holder;
 for (property in obj) {
 if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
   if(condition){
    promise_holder = fngetip(); 
     }
if(condition2){
     //some other code
     }
   }
 }
 promise_holder.then(function (ifChildren) {
                  obj.children = ifChildren;
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
              }
```

And finally a function where i am calling fnGetData

```
 TopoTree : function(children) {
 var treeArray;
 for (i = 0; i < children[i]; i++) {
         fnGetData(children[i]);
          }

                      treeArray.push(treeData);
                      return treeArray;
                  },
```

I dont want to return `TreeArray` before all promises are resolved of `fnGetData`.

How to wait for all promises to be resolved first and then return data?

I cannot use `promise.All` as I don't have `promise_holder` in `topotree` scope or am I thinking in wrong direction ?

Comment: You should reconsider your variable names. They are confusing. (http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2009/05/04/71-tips-for-naming-variables/)

Comment: they are sudo names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Have `fnGetData` return the `promise_holder` and have `TopoTree` collect them in an array and place the *completion logic* in a then function after `Promise.all()`

```
fnGetData: function(obj){
  var promise_holder;
  for (property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if(condition){
        promise_holder = fngetip(); 
      }
      if(condition2){
        //some other code
      }
    }
  }

  // RETURN THE PROMISE HERE!
  return promise_holder.then(function (ifChildren) {
    obj.children = ifChildren;
    // Return a value for use later:
    return ifChildren;
  });
}   

TopoTree : function(children) {
  var promises = [];
  for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    promises.push(fnGetData(children[i]));
  }

  // We are handling the result / rejections here so no need to return the
  // promise.
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(treeArray) {
      // Do something with treeArray
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

Comment: it says then undefined for Promise.all

Comment: This error to be precise 
"TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined "

Comment: `.all()` returns a promise that resolves when all iterable promises have resolved, so you should be able to `.then()` it. Are you using any specific promise library?

Comment: @mugheesilyas Acording to the ES6 spec page on MDN: "...returns a promise...". So the only way you could get undefined is if you are *not* using ES6 promises but instead some promise library that is obviously broken. Perhaps you should look into [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) as a better alternative. It behaves very well and is ES6 implementation compatible.

Comment: @mugheesilyas verify that `promise_holder` is actually a promise, maybe your error comes from there and not `Promise.all`.

Comment: promise_holder is actually a promise and promise.All gets resolved too.
but its .then part is not working for some reason. but your answer is right as i have tested it seperatly from my project.

Comment: @Sukima can we have two .then for same promise ? 
in your example we have .then for promise_holder and we have .then for promise.all as well and in essence they both are solving the same promise no ?

Comment: @mugheesilyas, promises are chainable and mutable. So for simplicity the answer is yes you can.